# convert va_list to fixed arguments

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am writing a thread spawning function of the prototype:

```
void Thread_create(void (*func)(void*), int argc, ...);
```

I have passed the argument count in so there is no problem determining the length.
The problem is how do I recast func to a function with argc length and then call it using the arguments that I have?

EDIT: I also have constrained the function to only accept void* arguments (i.e. no need to worry about any other type being passed in)

For example:

```
void foo(void *bar, void *baz);
void fooTwo(void *bar, void *baz, void *bam);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Thread_create(&foo, 2, (void*)argv[0], (void*)argv[1]); //foo gets called in a new thread with the arguments: argv[0] and argv[1]
    Thread_create(&fooTwo, 3, (void*)argv[0], (void*)argv[1], (void*)argv[2]); //fooTwo gets called in a new thread with the arguments: argv[0] and argv[1] and argv[2]
    return 0;
}
```

Side note: a solution of the form

```
Thread_create(void (*func)(void*), int argc, ...); //call with 1 arg
Thread_create(void (*func)(void*, void*), int argc, ...); //call with 2 args
Thread_create(void (*func)(void*, void*, void*), int argc, ...); //call with 3 args
```

doesn't work because I cannot pass that information across the thread create library call, whether it may be pthread_create or the windows ThreadCreate function.

Comment: I don't quite follow.  Are you saying that you have a pointer to a function that takes a fixed number of args?  Could you give an example of what you would like to be able to do?

Comment: Also, could you decide whether you're interested in C or C++?  The solutions could potentially be very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't construct a stack frame yourself, programmatically, unless you know the CPU architecture and ABI of the platform in question and code it yourself.

For instance, with general calling conventions on x86 32 bit, you need to pass arguments to the stack in reverse order (e.g. last argument first), then invoke the function via call, and once it returns clean the stack by popping up the values (or by adjusting the stack pointer).

So for a function "foo(int bar, int baz)" you would:

```
pushl <value-for-baz>
pushl <value-for-bar>
call  foo
addl  8, $esp
```

Perhaps you could also code this in C, but messing with the stack from C would definitely require some assembly magic.

Also, stack frames may even look different when using different compiler flags. x86_64 puts arguments in registers first, and only uses the stack when there are more arguments than registers.

In short, don't do that. :)

The only alternative would be to create a large conditional, where each branch would call the proper function with the required number of arguments, or overloaded function as you proposed, or using a data structure to pass this information, like outlined in the other answer.

```
Thread_create(void (*func)(void), int argc, ...)
{
  if (argc == 1)
     ((void (*)(void *)) func)(arg0);
  else if (argc == 2)
     ((void (*)(void *, void *)) func)(arg0, arg1); 
}
```

Comment: Yea, I was simply hoping that there might be some library which contained all the variants of the assembly.

Comment: On second consideration, what you say doesnt sound correct. There must be a uniform method of calling the function which doesnt simply shove the arguments into registers. The reason being that what if there were a pointer being passed to your second example of thread create? That would have to call the function correctly. Since the compiler cannot determine ahead of time what function is being called, all functions have to follow the convention. Am i missing something?

Comment: @chacham: All functions can follow the convention of putting the first N arguments into registers.

Comment: When you invoke a function through a pointer, then you always tell the compiler what kind of function it is: either through the original type of the pointer or via a cast.

In the example, I've used explicit casting and casted the same function pointer first to have a single argument and then two of them. This way the C compiler knows how to pass the arguments.

It is the property of the CPU and the ABI specification/calling convention how a given function call looks like. So once the compiler knows the type, it can invoke it, no matter where the pointer points.

Comment: Right, but what that means is that all functions of the same form, for example, "void foo(void*, void*)", MUST pass the arguments the same way. The compiler cannot decide that it wants some of the functions matching that format to have the arguments passed via registers and other via the stack.

Comment: that's right. the prototype defines how it needs to be called. theoretically you can also construct a call sequence dynamically, from your code. I just said that you need to write that code according to the current CPU / ABI. And programatically creating a stack frame requires assembly code too, since you can't control the registers from C code.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't what variable arguments are for. Better just take an aditional `void*` parameter that gets passed back to the user function. This is the usual way that callbacks with user data are implemented.

```
typedef void (*ThreadMainFunc)(void*);

void ThreadCreate(ThreadMainFunc func, void* user_data){
  // do whatever you need to do
  func(user_data);
  // whatever else
}

struct ThreadData{
  // arguments here as member
  int arg1;
  double arg2;
};

void MyThreadMain(void* my_data){
  ThreadData* my_real_data =(ThreadData*)my_data;
  // use my_real_data here
}

int main(){
  ThreadData data;
  data.arg1 = 42;
  data.arg2 = 13.37;
  CreateThread(&MyThreadMain,&data);
//                           ^^^^^ --- you don't need to cast to void, only from void
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot change the functions prototype, it is a library call

Comment: @chacham15: Which function prototype? That of the `ThreadMainFunc`?

Comment: Of the function being called. I.e. "void foo(void *bar, void *baz); " is a part of a library. Yes, I could create a function which wraps it, but to do so for every function call to the library is a tedious waste of time.

Comment: Its in the //use my_real_data here part of your code. Essentially, you wrapped the function. But I want to call any of 1000 different functions in a new thread. See the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible if you don't want to code the calling site in assembly for every possible architecture out there. :/

Comment: which is why, as i posted in the other answer, i was looking for a library which takes care of that for me. :)